# MySQL Amazon RDS: Lock Wait timeout exceeded

Tags: mysql, timeout, deadlock, amazon-rds

On Mysql (Amazon RDS), when I try to run the following SQL query

```
UPDATE
    table1 INNER JOIN table2 USING (CommonColumn)
SET
    table1.col1 = table2.x,
    table1.col2 = table2.y
```

I get this error after around 52 seconds consistently:

```
Error Code: 1205. Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

How should I resolve this?

table2 has around 17 million records and table2 which is a subset of table1 has 4 million records. Could it be the size of the tables that is the problem or is something wrong with my query?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I restarted the MySQL instance and the same query worked.

Comment: As I told you. Someone had a lock on some of those resources. So, restarting closed all connections and resources were released :P

Comment: and if the problem persists?

Comment: if the problem persists, use innotop to look at what is blocking the locks. you can then close the connection associated with the blocking lock (killing the offending process can cause mysqld to panic and crash in versions of 5.5)

Answer (score 4):

Try increasing the default number of IO threads if you are using InnoDB engine. RDS defaults to a measly 4. You will need to restart the DB instance for the Parameter Group to use the new values as they are not "dynamic" (require a reboot).

`show variables like 'innodb_%io_threads';
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| innodb_read_io_threads  | 4     |
| innodb_write_io_threads | 4     |
+-------------------------+-------+`

Comment: I'm unable to edit this on RDS aurora "Variable 'innodb_write_io_threads' is a read only variable""

Comment: Aurora DB is a proprietary, MySQL-look-alike product. Its configuration variables may be protected, incompatible or outright for show. The instructions above were for managed MySQL instances (RDS MySQL). You will need to contact Aurora support team re. your specific problem.

Comment: too late for the comment, yet, RDS parameters are editable from the AWS console. Some changes may need restart

Answer (score -1):

On AWS RDS, I had a DB instance fill up, which caused this error on the client.