# Magento 1.8 & Amazon RDS Lock wait timeouts

Tags: mysql, magento, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Firstly this isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060181/magento-and-amazon-rds-timeouts) because I'm not behind a load balancer at the moment. Also [randomly restarting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060560/mysql-amazon-rds-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded) the instance isn't a satisfactory solution either.

I moved our store from using a local mysql db on the EC2 to RDS recently and we're getting some errors on the backend when they're moving categories around / adding products. Mostly they look like `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction` but I've seen other variations of PDO errors.

How would one go about eliminating these issues?

I've read suggestions to just 'keep retrying' but this seems stupid.

I've tried tinkering with `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` and others but doesn't seem to resolve it.

I have finally disabled magento logging to the DB - will see if this helps going forward. Unfortunately I have to wait a while to let the staff tinker on the backend and then see if any fix has an effect.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Now also seeing a bunch of these

```
User Error: DDL statements are not allowed in transactions
```

Comment: What size is your RDS db?

Comment: I was using a Large. Downgraded to a Small recently and it had no effect. The activity log in the RDS dashboard seems normal?:

CPU 10%
DB Connections 1 or 2
Freeable Space 100,000MB
Freeable Memory 500 MB
Write IOPS 50 - 150
Read IOPS 3
Queue Depth 0.75 - 0
Replica Lag 0

Anything stand out to you from those numbers?